# Tailwind: how to target the last ul of a div's children?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have a `<div>` and it has a list of indirect `ul` as children:

```
<div class="bg-white">
  <div> // 1st child block
    <nav>
      <ul>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div> // 2nd child block
    <nav>
      <ul>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  ... // 5 blocks in total
</div>
```

In Tailwind, how to target the last child block's `ul` only, I tried `[&_ul:nth-child(5)]:right-0`, `[&_ul:last]:right-0`, `[&_ul]:last:right-0`, none worked.

Comment: try `[&_div:nth-last-child(1)_ul]:right-0`